# Can I upgrade UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities from opengles-1 to opengles-2 in iOS app

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, xcode4, permissions, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I’m upgrading my app from cocos2d-x 1.x to 2.x that means change from OpenGLES 1.0 to 2.0,

I've updated my Info.plist settings to reflect the change

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<dict>
    <key>accelerometer</key>
    <true/>
    <key>opengles-2</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Change from opengles-1 to opengles-2

But while installing application from XCode 4.5 GM (the older version was compiled with prevoius XCode) I receive error:

**Could not change executable permissions on the application**

Comment: I don't think this is related. Try deleting the app from your device/simulator and run again. Reboot your device & Mac if problem persists. Sometimes the connection between Xcode & device breaks, for example with Xcode 4.4 I used to have to restart Xcode every 20 times I deployed an app to the Simulator because Xcode wouldn't recognize that the Simulator/App wasn't running anymore.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D deleting the app helped, but I'm still concerned about this error. The question is can I upgrade from opengles-1 to opengles-2? Will it pass iTunes's certification process?